# What will happen when someone (with 2000+ rep) opens a question which has pending version?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits, privileges

If SO shows a popup dialog or notification to the users who have the privilege of verifying pending versions (even other privileges, like close vote, delete vote, reopen vote, etc.), and reminds them to verify it, the collaboration efficiency will be better.

Dose SO has that function yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The edit link changes to let yo know that there is a pending revision on that post. Clicking on the link you have the option to accept, reject or improve the edit. On the same note, if a post has closing votes, there is a notification on it. Clicking there you have the option to check what other votes have been cast.

Is that what you're asking for? It's not an annoying popup, but a much gentler notification. I would *hate* being attacked by popups in every post that has a pending revision, vote or flag!